# How to set calendar using PrimeNG calendar?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I have a calendar control and I want to set some value to it, but I get the following error on the below line and value also does not get set.

```
this.data.dateIn = this.selecteddata.dateIn;

<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="data.dateIn" [showIcon]="true" name="dateInCalendar"   
             required #dateInCalendar="ngModel">
</p-calendar>
```

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: date.getMonth is not a 
>   function
>       TypeError: date.getMonth is not a function
>           at Calendar.webpackJsonp.../../../../primeng/components/calendar/calendar.js.Calendar.formatDate
>   (calendar.js:649)
>           at Calendar.webpackJsonp.../../../../primeng/components/calendar/calendar.js.Calendar.updateInputfield
>   (calendar.js:252)
>           at Calendar.webpackJsonp.../../../../primeng/components/calendar/calendar.js.Calendar.writeValue
>   (calendar.js:595)
>           at forms.es5.js:1779
>           at forms.es5.js:2965
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at FormControl.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormControl.setValue
>   (forms.es5.js:2965)
>           at forms.es5.js:4367
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:365)
>           at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:364)
>           at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:125)
>           at zone.js:758
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:398)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>           at Calendar.webpackJsonp.../../../../primeng/components/calendar/calendar.js.Calendar.formatDate
>   (calendar.js:649)
>           at Calendar.webpackJsonp.../../../../primeng/components/calendar/calendar.js.Calendar.updateInputfield
>   (calendar.js:252)
>           at Calendar.webpackJsonp.../../../../primeng/components/calendar/calendar.js.Calendar.writeValue
>   (calendar.js:595)
>           at forms.es5.js:1779
>           at forms.es5.js:2965
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at FormControl.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormControl.setValue
>   (forms.es5.js:2965)
>           at forms.es5.js:4367
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:365)
>           at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:364)
>           at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:125)
>           at zone.js:758
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:398)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>           at resolvePromise (zone.js:710) [angular]
>           at :4200/polyfills.bundle.js:7469:17 [angular]
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881) [angular]
>           at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:591) []
>           at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:464) []

Comment: post the code which has date.getmonth

Comment: @Sajeetharan Seems it's from primeng https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts#L1235

Comment: I see you are a .Net developer. Cool you are PrimeFaces on that platform. Did not know you could run JSF or, more generic, java code on .Net...

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have no such method named as date.getmonth

Comment: @yurzui but how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue, providing the solution for helping others, Just convert `selecteddata.dateIn` to `.toDate()`.

```
this.data.dateIn = this.selecteddata.dateIn.toDate();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TypeError: date.getMonth is not a function
```

=> I think you are using the function to get the month from the date. But the date is invalid or wrong format. That's why your format function doesn't work.

With my idea, Please use moment.js to wrap your date first. example :

```
let selectedDate = moment(dateString);
```

If you want to get month, you just use :

```
let month = ("0"+(selectedEndDate.get("month")+1)).slice(-2);
```

Your format date is invalid with p-calendar. you can use and pass it to the Calendar:

```
this.currentDate = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```